# Jenkins binaries folder empty

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I use jenkins and sonar plugin,tfs plugin. It can get the project files from tfs but jenkins doesn't create the binaries folder. If I start build from jenkins it gives an eror, build failed. How can I resolve this problem?

```
Sonar-runner.properties
#Project identification  
sonar.projectKey=key:Test
sonar.projectName=Test
sonar.projectVersion=10.00.00

#Info required for Sonar  
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt=true
sonar.visualstudio.outputPaths=Source/testproject/binaries
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true
sonar.visualstudio.solution=Source/testproject/testproject_AllProjects.sln
sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=Source/testproject/binaries
sonar.fxcop.mode=active
```

Error;

```
11:47:08.986 INFO  - Using the following Visual Studio solution:  C:\workspace\Source\testproject\testproject_AllProjects.sln
11:47:09.122 INFO  - Using the assembly output paths specified using the property "sonar.visualstudio.outputPaths" set to:  C:\workspace\Source\testproject\binaries    11:47:09.136 INFO  - Using the the following assembly for project Ad.SilverFile: C:\workspace\Source\testproject\binaries\Ad.SilverFile.dll

.....

ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find the assembly "C:\workspace\Source\testproject\binaries\Ad.SilverFile.dll" provided by the property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly".
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopConfiguration.checkAssemblyProperty(FxCopConfiguration.java:104)
at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopConfiguration.checkProperties(FxCopConfiguration.java:87)
at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopSensor.analyse(FxCopSensor.java:91)
at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopSensor.analyse(FxCopSensor.java:86)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the new MSBuild SonarQube Runner to analyze .NET projects - the sonar-runner and the Visual Studio Bootstrapper are being retired. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin for more information.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, thank you, how to identify specific solution file for msbuild sonarqube runner. It gives an error "Please set sonar.visualstudio.solution to explicitly tell which one to use."

Comment: This message occurs because you have the Visual Studio Bootstrapper plugin still installed on your SonarQube server. Disable it on your project by passing `/d:sonar.visualstudio.enable=false` to the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin` command. Now, the MSBuild SonarQube Runner will analyze all .NET solutions/projects built with `msbuild` in between the `begin` and `end` command invocations.